Show that $\sum_{i=1}^n{i/2^i} < 2$
Show that $\sum_{i=1}^n{i/2^i} < 2$
The book says that I could try to bound the sum with a geometric progression. I've tried finding progressions that bounds this sum and equals 2, but with no such luck...
But, can I do this?
$$\log{\sum_{i=1}^n{i/2^i}} < \log{2}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\log{(i/2^i)} < 1$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\log{(i)}-i < 1$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\log{i} < \sum_{i=1}^n i+1$$
Assuming that the logarithm is $\log_2.$ I believe that any $\log_m$ also should work?

No, that does not work. In general,
$$
\log(x+y) \ne \log + \log y
$$
Consider, for instance, base $e$ logarithm and $x=y=\frac e 2$. Then
$$
1 = \log e = \log \left( \frac e 2 + \frac e 2 \right)
\ne 2 \log \frac e 2
= 2 \log e - 2 \log 2
= 2   - 2 \log 2
\approx 0.61
$$The property you're thinking of is
$$
\log (xy) = \log(x) + \log(y)
$$

@PrincessEev thanks for pounting this out. I understand it, just made a mistake.

@Riemann this answer my question, sorry for the duplicate but it didn't appear in my search for some reason...

Note that $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n ix^i = x \dfrac{d}{dx} \sum_{i=1}^n x^i = x \frac{d}{dx}\dfrac{x-x^{n+1}}{1-x}.$
Differentiating and evaluating in $x = \dfrac{1}{2}$ gives
$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{i}{2^i} = 2^{-n}(-n+2^{n+1}-2) = 2 - \dfrac{n+2}{2^n}.$
Can you justify the claim?
